# Hide Authorization From Inspect Element

Tags: angularjs, api, request

I'm using angular and http interceptor for set the default header Authorization.

But the problem is every time I inspect element there are always request header.

```
Authorization:dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

I don't think it safe for the app to shown the Authorization.

Is there any way to hide the request header?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945227/is-there-any-solution-to-hide-authorization-from-request-headers-or-hide-token