# Is there any solution to hide Authorization from request headers or hide token

Tags: angular, authorization, token, bearer-token, request-headers

I'm trying to secure my web site, i want to hide Authorization or just hide token.

i'm using angular 7, and IIS server.

this is when i use my token in Front-end side:

```
   var headerOptions = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token,
        'contrat_token': this.contrat_token
    }); 

    let options = new RequestOptions({
        search: params,
        headers: headerOptions
    });

    return this._http.get(url, options).pipe(map(resp => {
        if (resp.status === 401 || resp.status == 401 || resp.status.toString() == "401") {
            this.clearCookie();
        }
        else {
            let reponse = JSON.parse(resp.json());

            if (reponse == -1 || reponse == "-1") {
                this.router.navigate(["/"]);
            }
        }

        return JSON.parse(resp.json())
    }
    ), catchError((error) => {
        if (error.status == 401 || error.status == "401") {
            this.clearCookie();
        }
        return of();
    })
    );
```

i see that in **request headers** :

```
     Authorization: Bearer THL8iBl4y4QTMh8sz8UluO3vDbtVib2Axp-_zYcPRGQVesnzDJVdFVq3GsYXeo4znSMbGqKNmLcGL_inNsMWAtc22
```

i want to see something like :

```
      Authorization: Bearer ******************
```

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: No..but you can add encryption/decryption into token..so that it will not get hacked..

Comment: @PrashantMBhavsar yes i add encryption/decryption into token but if someOne send to server the token encrypted the server will decrypt it, for that i want to hide it

Comment: To send encrypted token to server, hacker should aware of actual token value..so that will not be case..

Comment: @PrashantMBhavsar is it the same case for **contrat_token**?

Comment: Yes..using same way in my current application..tried to hack token and access application using postman etc but no luck..

Comment: Why would you do it? Why do you think sending the token is insecure?

Comment: @MichalCumpl if someOne send to server the token encrypted the server will decrypt it, for that i want to hide it

Comment: Are you sure you understand the OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token concept and usage?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838183/what-is-the-oauth-2-0-bearer-token-exactly/25843058

Comment: if your validating audience/issuer they cannot just steal your token and re-use it elsewhere the token read about JWT

Comment: @Saad- Did you get any solution?

Comment: @piyush_systematix no you can't do it beacause it's normal to display the token

Comment: What we are avoiding is that we don't to reuse the token by someone else. The only solution to that is to make it short lived. For every request to the api we must request for a new access token. The lifetime should be no more than 30 minutes.